# Matching an empty input box using CSS

Tags: css, input, css-selectors

How do I apply a style to an empty input box? If the user types something in the input field, the style should no longer be applied. Is this possible in CSS? I tried this:

```
input[value=""]
```

Answer (score 255):

In modern browsers you can use [`:placeholder-shown`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder-shown/) to target the empty input (not to be confused with [`::placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder)).

```
input:placeholder-shown {
    border: 1px solid red; /* Red border only if the input is empty */
}
```

In HTML you must set the placeholder attribute. Chrome browser requires at least a space character as value.

```
<input type="text" placeholder=" "> <!-- Do not remove placeholder -->
```

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb It does seem to require a placeholder attribute (with a value) to be present in the input tag. Tested in Chrome - not sure if this counts for all browsers.

Comment: Placeholder attribute have to be set. Anyway we can set placeholder attribute as whitespace.

Comment: Example of it in production use https://codepen.io/fossprime/pen/BdWeNr?editors=1100 

I used this in production while having graceful degradability... it looks and feels better if supported, but isn't a usability issue if it's not.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb It only seems to work if there is a non-empty placeholer https://codepen.io/ryanve/pen/XejOzG

Comment: @Amanpreet According to https://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder, this won't work in IE 11 either (or Edge).

Comment: Not supported in Microsoft browsers at all: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder-shown

Comment: `:-ms-input-placeholder` seems to work in IE11 as long as the placeholder isn't an empty string, i.e. `placeholder=" "` (a single space) works OK for me.

Comment: It's supported in Edge v79 onward (since Edge v79 onward is Chromium-based).

Comment: it doesn't work for me! Tested it in Safari, Chrome and Firefox but it's doing nothing.

Comment: It's now supported in edge since v79. @trueToastedCode you have to set the placeholder-attribute like placeholder=" " - empty string does not work (tested in Chrome).

Answer (score 179):

If only the field is `required` you could go with `input:valid`

```css
#foo-thing:valid + .msg { visibility: visible!important; }
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="foo-thing" required="required">
 <span class="msg" style="visibility: hidden;">Yay not empty</span>
```

See [live on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qMLq/1/)

OR negate using `#foo-thing:invalid` (credit to @SamGoody)

Comment: ..or negate by using :invalid{} https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F%3Ainvalid

Comment: I want same thing, but my field is not required. is there any way to do so?

Comment: @ZahidulIslamRuhel of course, this answer should not be the top one. see the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/35593489/11293716

Answer (score 29):

`input[value=""], input:not([value])`

works with:

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" value="" />
```

But the style will not change as soon as someone will start typing (you need JS for that).

Comment: Not reliable as the value attribute is not changed in DOM after a field edit. However, nice trick if you don't care about this - and works in latest Safari, Chrome, FF and IE...

Comment: To match the former, you can use `input[value=""], input:not([value])`.

Answer (score 23):

Updating the value of a field does not update its value attribute in the DOM so that's why your selector is always matching a field, even when it's not actually empty.

Instead use the [`invalid` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ainvalid) to achieve what you want, like so:

```css
input:required {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
input:required:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input required type="text" value="">

<input required type="text" value="Value">
```

Answer (score 12):

I realize this is a very old thread, but things have changed a bit since and it did help me find the right combination of things I needed to get my problem fixed. So I thought I'd share what I did.

The problem was I needed to have the same css applied for an optional input if it was filled, as I had for a filled required. The css used the psuedo class :valid which applied the css on the optional input also when not filled.

This is how I fixed it;

HTML

```
<input type="text" required="required">
<input type="text" placeholder="">
```

CSS

```
input:required:valid {
    ....
}
input:optional::not(:placeholder-shown){
    ....
}
```

Comment: What if I need to use it in multiple input fields with actual content in their respective placeholders?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but if the only difference is that you want to have actual placeholders then just add that text instead of the empty string and it should work the same way (in theory, i haven't tested it)

Answer (score 11):

If supporting legacy browsers is not needed, you could use a combination of `required`, `valid`, and `invalid`.

The good thing about using this is the `valid` and `invalid` pseudo-elements work well with the type attributes of input fields. For example:

```css
input:invalid, textarea:invalid { 
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d45252;
    border-color: #b03535
}

input:valid, textarea:valid {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #5cd053;
    border-color: #28921f;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required />
<input type="url" name="website" placeholder="http://johndoe.com"/>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" required/>
```

For reference, JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/0sf6m46j/

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

For the HTML, add the `required` attribute to the input element

```
<input class="my-input-element" type="text" placeholder="" required />
```

For the CSS, use the `:invalid` selector to target the empty input

```
input.my-input-element:invalid {

}
```

**Notes:**

- About `required` from [w3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp):
  "When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form."

Answer (score 8):

```
$('input#edit-keys-1').blur(function(){
    tmpval = $(this).val();
    if(tmpval == '') {
        $(this).addClass('empty');
        $(this).removeClass('not-empty');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('not-empty');
        $(this).removeClass('empty');
    }
});
```

in jQuery. I added a class and styled with css.

```
.empty { background:none; }
```

Answer (score 7):

It worked for me to add a class name to the input and then apply CSS rules to that:

```
<input type="text" name="product" class="product" />

<style>
input[value=""].product {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

This question might have been asked some time ago, but as I recently landed on this topic looking for client-side form validation, and as the `:placeholder-shown` [support](https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aplaceholder-shown)  is getting better, I thought the following might help others.

Using [Berend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35593489/5711164) idea of using this CSS4 pseudo-class, I was able to create a form validation only triggered after the user is finished filling it.

Here is ademo and explanation on CodePen:
https://codepen.io/johanmouchet/pen/PKNxKQ

Answer (score 4):

If you're happy not not supporting IE or pre-Chromium Edge (which might be fine if you are using this for progressive enhancement), you can use `:placeholder-shown` as Berend has said. Note that for Chrome and Safari you actually need a non-empty placeholder for this to work, though a space works.

```css
*,
 ::after,
 ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label.floating-label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 2.2em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

label.floating-label input {
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 2.2em;
  padding-top: 0.7em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

label.floating-label input:focus {
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #80bdff;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
}

label.floating-label input+span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0em;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.66em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: font-size 0.1s ease-in-out, top 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

label.floating-label input:placeholder-shown {
  padding-top: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
}

label.floating-label input:placeholder-shown+span {
  top: 0.3em;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Floating labels example (no-JS)
  </legend>
  <label class="floating-label">
    <input type="text" placeholder=" ">
    <span>Username</span>
  </label>
  <label class="floating-label">
    <input type="Password" placeholder=" ">
    <span>Password</span>
  </label>
</fieldset>
<p>
  Inspired by Bootstrap's <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/floating-labels/">floating labels</a>.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

So I was playing around earlier with the new :where and :is clauses and conceived of this bit of fun, and after finding this post with the :invalid and :placeholder-shown bits, thought I might share this possibility for future reference

```css
:required:where( input, textarea ):where( :placeholder-shown, :invalid ) {
    border-color: var(--warning);
}
```

which applies the `:root { --warning: orange; }` color to any required input or textarea, that is either empty or invalid. And that is just downright *sexy*

Answer (score 1):

While no browser currently (2021-10-01) supports it, there is a proposal for a `:blank` pseudo-class.

ref:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:blank.
Do note, this is **experimental**, and **no** browser supports it as of now.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can make it possible. don't forget to set `placeholder=" "` and `required` attr to your inputs. you can change the props as you wish.

```css
body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.input-gp {
    margin-top: 150px;
    position: relative;
    
}
.input-gp input {
    position: relative;
    
}
.input-gp label{
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}
.input-gp input:placeholder-shown + label{
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 5px;
}
.input-gp input:focus + label,
.input-gp input + label{
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="input-gp ">
<input  type="email" name="" id="email" placeholder=" "       required>
   <label class=" position-absolute" for="email"> Email</label>
  </div>
  
 </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm wondered by answers we have clear attribute to get empty input boxes, take a look at this code

```
/*empty input*/
input:empty{
    border-color: red;
}
/*input with value*/
input:not(:empty){
    border-color: black;
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
input, select, textarea {
    border-color: @green;
    &:empty {
        border-color: @red;
    }
}
```

**More over** for having a great look in the validation

```
 input, select, textarea {
    &[aria-invalid="true"] {
        border-color: amber !important;
    }

    &[aria-invalid="false"], &.valid {
        border-color: green !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: `:empty` applies only to elements that have no children. Inputs can't have child nodes at all so your input will be always with red border. Also see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617020/matching-an-empty-input-box-using-css#comment23212939_3617050)

Comment: @NasserHadjloo have you tested this? Changing the `value` doesn't change the number of child nodes.

Comment: @jcuenod what do you mean by number of child nodes? I didn't get your point

Comment: In xml structures, nodes are nested (i.e. `<parent><child></child></parent>`). You just have `<input></input>` and as you type what's changing is not a `<value>` node inside `<input>` but a value *attribute*: `<input value='stuff you type'></input>`

Comment: @jcuenod Honestly speaking, I don't get your point at all, I suggest you test my proposition and you will see that it will work

Comment: Your `aria-invalid="true"` selector will work. However, your `:empty` selector will not: http://jsfiddle.net/5ezdhemb/ (note that it stays red because no child nodes are created when the value changes)

Comment: @jcuenod yes You are right, but still when you are validating the form, before submitting, you will see the border-color change

Comment: But that's not what the OP is trying to achieve.