# CSS apply style to empty inputs ([value=''])

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to apply a special style to all inputs in my form that are required and empty at that.

It does work when i write in my css

```
input[required='required'] {
    bla-bla-bla;
}
```

but it doesn't work, when i write

```
input[value=''] {
   bla-bla-bla;
}
```

I know i can do that using jQuery, but i would like to do that in pure css, if it is possible.

Can that be done?

Thank you in advance, 
Timofey.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matching an empty input box using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617020/matching-an-empty-input-box-using-css)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Searched *css style empty inputs* and found the following:

[Matching an empty input box using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617020/matching-an-empty-input-box-using-css)

You need to use JavaScript.

To use the CSS style, you would have to type in the attribute: `value=''` in your HTML, but then the CSS would match regardless of if the value changes mid-session.

Comment: Thanks, but that's kind of sad ;)

Answer (score 23):

If you don't have to support older IE versions, you can set the `placeholder` attribute on your input to something (can be whitespace, but must be something) and use `:placeholder-shown` to target that input.

```html
<input type="text" class="custom-input" placeholder=" ">
```

```css
.custom-input:placeholder-shown {
    /* Your rules */
}
```

Comment: But input type file seems never :placeholder-shown (FF)

Answer (score 14):

You can use the Pseudo-Selecot **:invalid** for this - it will match an input only when the browser-validation fails for the element. If you set the element *required* it will be invalid as long as it is empty.

And all moder browsers support this CSS-class: [Browser Compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation)

```css
input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" required>
```

Comment: What if I don't want to have the input required?

Comment: @Fanky If you want the style to auto-update without JavaScript you will need required or use the placeholder tag. But with a file-input you will most likely involve JavaScript anyway.

Comment: Well yes, I ended up with `jQuery( 'input[type=file]' ).change( function( e ) { this.defaultValue = this.value; } );` and CSS `:not([value=""])` which doesn't work without the former.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<input type="text" value="">
```

```css
input:not([value=""]) {
    /* Your code */
}
```