# No Print css empty FORM fields

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to add a empty form field `no-print` insert for a FORM? Any empty form fields I do not want to print

```
@media print
{    
    .no-print, .no-print *
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is a question?

Comment: @AlexFilatov forgot to add the question mark

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matching an empty input box using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617020/matching-an-empty-input-box-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

I assume this will do the trick:

```
window.onbeforeprint = function() {
        var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll("input"),
            inputElementsLength = inputElements.length;
        for(var i=0; i< inputElementsLength, i++) {
            if(!inputElements[i].value) { // if empty
                inputElements[i].classList.add("no-print");
            }
        }
    };
```