# Can't select empty input with input[value=""]?

Tags: html, css, input, css-selectors

I'm trying to mark required (and empty inputs) like this

```css
input:required {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
input[value=""]:required {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" required>

<input type="text" value="Not empty" required>
```

It seems to work, but once you set a value to the input, it still marked

Comment: I think It is not possible by pure css.

Comment: I think it's answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952526/detect-if-an-input-has-text-in-it-using-css

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34001991/4768433).

Comment: @Shaggy now we're talking! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind using JavaScript you could use an if-statement to give a class based on whether or not the input contains text.
then use you CSS on those classes.

Comment: I know, that way it would be done a while a go, but just curious why i doesnt work

Comment: now Im curious too..