# How to make default style work when checking validation?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```css
input {
  background: white;
  color: white;
}
input:in-range {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
input:out-of-range {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h3> CSS range validation </h3>
Enter your age
<input type="number" min="1" max="100">
```

## Aim:

- white for out-of-range (default case)
- green for in-range
- red for out-of-range

In the above snippet, how can one make

```
input {
   background: white;
   color: white;
}
```

work for just `input` regardless of `in-range` or `out-of-range`?

Comment: what you want ? can you tell specifically what you want?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud I need to make `background: white;` work

Comment: You are allready define min or max if you used to this than used to jquery or javascript code

Comment: @RohitAzad Validation without `.js`. Thats the idea

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d44h8ajj/ is this ok?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud `in-range` and `out-of-range` are not working

Comment: Its because of the `!important`. Try to avoid using `!important` at all costs.

Comment: @WilliamCallahan I also prefer not using `!important`

Comment: @student: This seems a bit like the `:valid`/`:invalid` pseudo where the values are considered as either `:in-range` or `:out-of-range` and so the default selector is always overriden by the pseudo-classes. [The spec says nothing about this](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#range-pseudos).

Comment: @Harry how will you handle this situation?

Comment: I think, Its impossible if you do not use `in-range` with `background:white;color:white;` instead of use `background:green;color:white;` because you already set `min` `range` so when you `input` anything then it is default state and also `in-range` state.So you should use `in-range` for get this result.

Comment: @student: Probably try giving the field a default value (like `value="0"`) and avoid the white background thing. Or, if the field is a mandatory field then there is another choice. Tell me, if it is one and I'll give that solution as answer.

Comment: @Harry value="0" makes the field `red`. This will certainly deteriorate UX. This field is mandatory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the `:in-range` and `:out-of-range` pseudo-classes work similar to the `:valid` and the `:invalid` pseudo-selectors. When this is applied, the `input` always seems to be in of the two states and because of it the default selector never gets applied. A blank value is also getting treated as in the range (though it shouldn't be). The [selectors spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#range-pseudos) doesn't seem to mention a handling for this case.

Ideally, I would recommend adding a default value for the field (like `value="0"`) because it is anyway a mandatory field for you. But, if you feel that the default red background affects your UX in a bad way then have a look at the below **workaround**.

Adding `required` attribute to the `input` (because it is anyway mandatory) and using it along with the `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudo-selectors seem to produce the required output.

- `input:invalid` - Applied for default scenario or blank value because field is required and so a blank value means invalid.
- `input:in-range:valid` - Any value that is in range and is valid would meet this selector.
- `input:out-of-range:invalid` - Any value that is out of range and invalid only because it is out of range will match this selector and so red color would come only when the value is out of range.

**Note to future readers:** This is also not very correct because if I am a user, I would expect a blank value for a required field also to be invalid and have a red background. So, this may not be a suitable workaround for you. Please validate and use accordingly.

```css
input:invalid {
  background: white;
  color: white;
}
input:in-range:valid {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
input:out-of-range:invalid {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h3> CSS range validation </h3>
Enter your age
<input type="number" min="1" max="100" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS cannot check whether or not a text box is empty under the conditions you are looking for. Below is a better approach to the solution, however your solution will require JavaScript. Please see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617020/matching-an-empty-input-box-using-css).

---

Try adding a class where the styles are only applied if the classes are on the element.

> CSS

```
input[type="number"] {
    background: white;
    color: black;
}
input[type="number"].validate:in-range {
    background: green;
    color: white;
}
input[type="number"].validate:out-of-range {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

> HTML

```
<h3> CSS range validation </h3>
Enter your age
<input class="validate" type="number" min="1" max="100">

<h3> NO CSS range validation </h3>
Enter your age
<input type="number" min="1" max="100">
```

Comment: It's not becoming green for `in-range` and becoming red for `out-of-range`