# Keep focus styling if text is present

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've got an input box. I customise it in normal state and on focus.

My question is how do I keep the focus CSS styling if text is present in the input box?

```
.par input[type=sample]{
    width:75px;
    background-color: #000;
}
.par input[type=sample]:focus{
    width:50px;
    background-color: #FF0;
}
```

Comment: A certain text or just any text? CSS cannot select and style elements based on content of text boxes.

Comment: @Harry Thanks. Any text.

Comment: It is still not straight-forward to achieve. Is your text box a mandatory field?

Comment: @Harry yes. It's a required field.

Comment: Would something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/rr5Lxshz/) be acceptable?

Comment: @Harry Thanks. It's pretty much same as mine. I want it to stay yellow if text has being typed (as per your sample)

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't saved it initially. Can you check the same link again?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617020/matching-an-empty-input-box-using-css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no pure CSS selectors to directly select and style text boxes based on their content. But if the field is a mandatory field (that is, you could add the `required` attribute) then the `:valid` pseudo selector can be used to identify if the text box has any text type inside it or not and based on it apply the required styles.

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 75px;
  background-color: #000;
}
input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=text]:valid {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" required />
<input type="text" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input[value=""]:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
}

<input onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="" />
```

another way would be to check in jquery.. using ':contains' selector

Answer (score -1):

you can have one more selector with :valid pseudo-class.

```
.par input[type=sample]:valid{
     width:50px;
     background-color: #FF0;
   }
```