# querySelectorAll detecting value in input

Tags: javascript, input, selectors-api

I have multiple inputs I want to discriminate according to whether the user enters a value in it or not.

```
<input type="text" class="foo"> <br/>
<input type="text" class="foo" value = "D"> <br/>
//and so on.. 

<button onclick="calculate()">Hightlight</button>
```

The code I wrote only works with attribute values, instead of detecting "manually" typed values before launching the function :

```
function calculate() {

  var allinputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[value][type="text"]:not([value=""])');
  var myLength = allinputs.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < myLength; ++i) {
    allinputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "lime";

  }
}
```

I only want to detect the inputs in which the user typed something when he submits it through the highlight button. 
Is there a way to do it in pure javascript ?

Here is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lau1989/Lytwyn8s/

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to select empty inputs using CSS selectors (see [Matching an empty input box using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617020/matching-an-empty-input-box-using-css)), but you can achieve what you want by testing the length of the value before applying the style:

```
function calculate() {
  var allinputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
  var myLength = allinputs.length;
  var input;

  for (var i = 0; i < myLength; ++i) {
    input = allinputs[i];
    if (input.value) {
        input.style.backgroundColor = "lime";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works when I type something in inputs with blank attributes value like <input value =""> but it still doesn't work when I type something in inputs with no value attributes. I could set blank attribute values to all my inputs, but I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do it ? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @Lau answer updated - removed `[value]` from the querySelectoAll so that it will now select all text inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check value like this

```js
function calculate() {
  var allinputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
  var myLength = allinputs.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < myLength; ++i) {
    if (allinputs[i].value == '') {
      allinputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "lime";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="foo">
<br/>
<input type="text" class="foo" value="D">
<br/>
<input type="text" class="foo" value="G">

<button onclick="calculate()">Hightlight</button>

<br/>
<br/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

See also [JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lytwyn8s/1/)

And if you want to remove lime background when user fills input and clicks again you can add `else` statement.

```js
function calculate() {
  var allinputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
  var myLength = allinputs.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < myLength; ++i) {
    if (allinputs[i].value == '') {
      allinputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "lime";
    }else {
     allinputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
        //allinputs[i].removeAttribute("style") or that
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="foo">
<br/>
<input type="text" class="foo" value="D">
<br/>
<input type="text" class="foo" value="G">

<button onclick="calculate()">Hightlight</button>

<br/>
<br/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

UPDATE

You need that

```js
function calculate() {
  var allinputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
  var myLength = allinputs.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < myLength; ++i) {
    if (!allinputs[i].hasAttribute("value")) {
        if(allinputs[i].value !== '') {
       allinputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "lime";
      }else {
        allinputs[i].removeAttribute("style");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="foo">
<br/>
<input type="text" class="foo" value="D">
<br/>
<input type="text" class="foo" value="G">

<button onclick="calculate()">Hightlight</button>

<br/>
<br/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: +1 for your help, although I'm not trying to select empty inputs, but only inputs with no value attributes in which the user typed something.