# without using form for validation How can I disabled a button in angular if <input> field is empty

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, angular2-databinding

I am trying to do **@output** in angular for that I have an input field with a button, I will send input's field data to parent by using @output() I want to disabled a button if the input field is empty, How can I disable without using form validation.

I tried this code

```
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "childInput" >
  <button [disabled] ="!childInput.value" (click)="sendToParent()">Send To Parent</button>
```

but it keeps disabled the button if the input field is empty or not.

> P.S I found answer with form validation but I didn't want to do with
>   form validation or defining a bool variable

Comment: Perhaps try `[disabled] ="!childInput.length"`

Comment: CSS? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617020/matching-an-empty-input-box-using-css

Comment: thank you @Und3rTow for your suggestions I have solved the problem

Comment: thank you @mplungjan for your suggestions I have solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code will work

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "childInput" >
<button [disabled] ="!childInput" (click)="sendToParent()">Send To Parent</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use ngModel:

```
<input type="text" #childInput >
<button [disabled]="!childInput.value.length>0" (click)="sendToParent()">Send To Parent</button>
```

Comment: I've tested it and for me it works without problems. The usage of reference variables is explained in [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html)

Comment: This works, but somehow it stops working if I use >10 or anything other than 0.