# How to add a class to multiple tags in a form at the same time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add a class to multiple tags in a form at the same time. Right now, i have the following code that adds the class for one tag

```
....
 // what form are you submitting?
 var form = $("#" + e.target.id);

 // value
 var value = 'category';

 // add class
 $("[name=" + value + "]", form).addClass("h-red");
```

I want to also add the class `h-red` to the tag with an id `checkbox-group1`

I've tried this with no success

```
$("[name=" + value + "]" ; "#checkbox-group1", form).addClass("h-red");
```

How?

Comment: why don't do use something like $("form>input") ?

Comment: how do i do that for multiple tags in relation to my example?

Comment: perhaps by adding a specific class to all those tags. like $("form>.required").toggleClass("h-red"); , and also comma separator in case of multiple matches. It's more about clearer code-style; I don't know if I'm right but I'm guessing your code is about form's input validation then with CSS like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617020/matching-an-empty-input-box-using-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `,` to seperate selectors.

```
$("[name='" + value + "'],#checkbox-group1,form").addClass("h-red");
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

And also, please enclose the value with `'`

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: this works ok.. form needs to be outside the double quotes though. thanks

Comment: Ohh.. I thought you want to add class `h-red` on `forms`. Great to know it works. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use like this:

```
$("[name='+ value +'], #checkbox-group1, form").addClass("h-red");
```