# jQuery get empty input

Tags: jquery, input

Until jQuery 1.8.3 I could get empty input using this code

```
$('#loginCard input[value=]').addClass('error');
```

After jQuery 1.8.3 this syntax does not work. What has changed?

I'd like to do the same thing with jQuery 3.2.1 without using functions or each like here:

```
$('#loginCard input').each(function (){ 
    if($(this).val()==""){
       $(this).addClass("error"); 
    }
});
```

following the concept "write less, do more"

Comment: You can use only css for this like describe in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11209779/863110) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact it worked without the quotes is a bug/feature which shouldn't have even been allowed in 1.8.3.

Add quotes, eg. `[value=""]`, and it works fine in any version of jQuery, past or present:

```js
$('#loginCard input[value=""]').addClass('error');
```

```css
.error { border: 1px solid #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loginCard">
  <input type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

If you need an alternative method to the attribute selector, you can use `filter()` like this:

```js
$('#loginCard input').filter(function() {
  return $(this).val().trim() == '';
}).addClass('error');
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to say that I have an input like this <div id="loginCard"><input type="text" /></div> 
I thought it worked anyway

Answer (score 0):

**Your Code Work in Steel This version, I hope your another problem affected this section. You Can Also Try This Code Here https://jsfiddle.net/tzk4a593/ Or Follow this code**

```js
jQuery("#loginCard").find('input').each(function (){ 
    if($(this).val()==""){
       $(this).addClass("error"); 
    }
});
```

```css
input.error { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<form id="loginCard" action="#">
  <input type="text" value="" name="one" />
   <input type="text" value="xxxxxx" name="some" />
  <input type="text" value="" name="two" />
  <input type="text" value="myVal" name="three" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though using quotes works, using `$item.val()` and using a CSS-Selector is not the same, as the latter doesnt' respect user input. Therefore the CSS-Selector-Solution will always display an error, even though the input is no longer empty:

https://codepen.io/MattDiMu/pen/aKzbgw