# React - Add Class to Empty Input Fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I want to add a red border only if an input is empty. I couldn't find a way to "addClass" in React so I'm using state. Right now the code will add red border to all inputs, even if it has text.

State:

```
this.state = {
  inputBorderError: false,
};
```

HTML/JSX:

```
<label>Name</label>
<input className={
  this.state.inputBorderError ? 'form-input form-input-fail' : 'form-input'
} />

<label>Email</label>
<input className={
  this.state.inputBorderError ? 'form-input form-input-fail' : 'form-input'
} />

<label>Message</label>
<textarea className={
  this.state.inputBorderError ? 'form-input form-input-fail' : 'form-input'
} />
```

CSS:

```
.form-input-fail {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

JS:

```
   let inputFields = document.getElementsByClassName('form-input');

   for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
      if (inputFields[i].value === '') {
        this.setState({
          inputBorderError: true,
        });
      }
    }
```

I see the error in my code as it's basically setting the state to true anytime it finds an empty input. I think I may be approaching this incorrectly as there's only one state. Is there a solution based on my state approach, or is there another solution?

Comment: Hi Eric, try out the codesandbox in my solution, I think it should cover all the bases. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo I'm looking into adding simple email validation. Have a thread on this, could use your expertise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56676342/react-adding-email-validation-to-empty-input-validation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, you have single state-value that affects all inputs, you should consider having one for each `input`. Also, your inputs are not controlled, it will be harder to record and track their values for error-handling.

It is good practice to give each `input` tag a name property. Making it easier to dynamically update their corresponding state-value.

Try something like the following, start typing into each input, then remove your text: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-feynman-vfmh5

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    inputs: {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      message: ""
    },
    errors: {
      name: false,
      email: false,
      message: false
    }
  };

  handleOnChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      inputs: {
        ...this.state.inputs,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
      },
      errors: {
        ...this.state.errors,
        [event.target.name]: false
      }
    });
  };

  handleOnBlur = event => {
    const { inputs } = this.state;
    if (inputs[event.target.name].length === 0) {
      this.setState({
        errors: {
          ...this.state.errors,
          [event.target.name]: true
        }
      });
    }
  };

  handleOnSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { inputs, errors } = this.state;
    //create new errors object
    let newErrorsObj = Object.entries(inputs)
      .filter(([key, value]) => {
        return value.length === 0;
      })
      .reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
        if (value.length === 0) {
          obj[key] = true;
        } else {
          obj[key] = false;
        }
        return obj;
      }, {});

    if (Object.keys(newErrorsObj).length > 0) {
      this.setState({
        errors: newErrorsObj
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { inputs, errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input
            className={
              errors.name ? "form-input form-input-fail" : "form-input"
            }
            name="name"
            value={inputs.name}
            onChange={this.handleOnChange}
            onBlur={this.handleOnBlur}
          />

          <label>Email</label>
          <input
            className={
              errors.email ? "form-input form-input-fail" : "form-input"
            }
            name="email"
            value={inputs.email}
            onChange={this.handleOnChange}
            onBlur={this.handleOnBlur}
          />

          <label>Message</label>
          <textarea
            className={
              errors.message ? "form-input form-input-fail" : "form-input"
            }
            name="message"
            value={inputs.message}
            onChange={this.handleOnChange}
            onBlur={this.handleOnBlur}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what does the three dots ... represent?

Comment: it's called a spread operator. It basically copies the state to another object.

Comment: @EricNguyen sorry about that. Yes, essentially it just means you want to take the existing key-value pairs from an existing object and use them in your new object. Let me know if you have any other questions :)

Comment: @ChristopherNgo why do you have "const { inputs, errors } = this.state;" in render function?

Comment: @EricNguyen that is called object destructuring. You take a key from an object and use it to declare a new variable, assigning it the value from the original key-value pair. This is essentially equivalent to `const inputs = this.state.inputs` and `const errors = this.state.errors`

Comment: @ChristopherNgo I understand the destructuring element but initially wondering why you declared it in render method. I think it's so you don't have to reference 'this.sate' every-time you reference specific state. Thanks, you've helped me a lot!

Comment: @EricNguyen that is exactly why I did that ;). You're very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that there is only one state.

What you need to do is store a separate error for each input. one way to do this is with a set or array on state like `state = {errors: []}`  and then check

```
<label>Name</label>
<input className={
  this.state.errors.includes('name') ? 'form-input form-input-fail' : 'form-input'
} />

<label>Email</label>
<input className={
  this.state.errors.includes('email') ? 'form-input form-input-fail' : 'form-input'
} />
} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep track of the input value in the state instead of checking for borderStyling state only.

Base on your code, you could refactor it to something like this:

```
// keep track of your input changes
this.state = {
  inputs: {
    email: '',
    name: '',
    comment: '',
  },
  errors: {
    email: false,
    name: false,
    comment: false,
  }
};

// event handler for input changes

handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    const inputChanges = {
       ...state.inputs,
       [name]: value
    }

    const inputErrors = {
       ...state.errors,
       [name]: value == ""
    }

    setState({
      inputs: inputChanges,
      errors: inputErrors,
    });
}
```

HTML/JSX

```
// the name attribut for your input

<label>Name</label>
<input name="name" onChange={handleChange} className={
  this.errors.name == "" ? 'form-input form-input-fail' : 'form-input'
} />

<label>Email</label>
<input name="email" onChange={handleChange} className={
  this.errors.email == "" ? 'form-input form-input-fail' : 'form-input'
} />

<label>Message</label>
<textarea name="comment" onChange={handleChange} className={
  this.errors.comment == "" ? 'form-input form-input-fail' : 'form-input'
} />
```

And if you are probably looking at implementing it with CSS and js, you can try this article [matching-an-empty-input-box-using-css-and-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617020/matching-an-empty-input-box-using-css)

But try and learn to make your component reusable and Dry, because that is the beginning of enjoying react app.

[Revised]