# React - adding email validation to empty input validation

Tags: reactjs, forms, email-validation

In React, I'm looking to add email validation (checks for @ and .com) to a form that currently checks for empty input fields.

I [found this](https://codepen.io/cesarwbr/pen/vKqxpZ) that does the job but can't figure out how to connect it to onSubmit along w/ my other validation.

Here's the [link to this project's codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/vqydRO) for complete code.

Setting initial State for inputs and errors:

```
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  inputs: {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    message: '',
  },
  errors: {
    name: false,
    email: false,
    message: false,
  },
};
```

}

JS Handling Input, onBlur

```
updateInput = e => {
this.setState({
  inputs: {
    ...this.state.inputs,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
  },

  errors: {
    ...this.state.errors,
    [e.target.name]: false,
  },
});
};

handleOnBlur = e => {
const { inputs } = this.state;
if (inputs[e.target.name].length === 0) {
  this.setState({
    errors: {
      ...this.state.errors,
      [e.target.name]: true,
    },
  });
}
};
```

Comment: What's the problem? You have a code sample that works, why aren't you just following that?

Comment: Eric, does the email have to end in .com?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo ideally yes

Comment: @EricNguyen see my solution below. Let me know if you have any questions. :)

Comment: HTML5 checks email when you use <input type="email" ....

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherNgo I'm playing around w/ your solution and my own. Making a mess but getting closer.

Comment: @EricNguyen sweet, let me know your thoughts, my solution should just be a template for how you would be able to get this done.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo I'm handling email validation onBlur, which works, but only when I click into the input field twice. Why isn't it recognizing the loss of focus the first time? See codepen https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/vqydRO

Comment: @EricNguyen because in your handleOnBlur, you still have to update the errors object in your state if the email is invalid. That errors object is connected to each input and will change the border to red if it is invalid. See updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VJPQvV

Comment: @EricNguyen any luck?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Thanks! How come the message doesn't appear on loss of focus? it's contained within the same event.

Comment: @EricNguyen its most likely because you're using document-selectors to directly change the innerHTML of elements. With React, it would be more beneficial to you to simply have some JSX that toggles the display of the error-message when there is an error.

Comment: @EricNguyen try the updated sandbox: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VJPQvV?editors=1111 That should work like you expect. Also please consider upvoting and marking my answer as the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195303/discussion-between-eric-nguyen-and-christopher-ngo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without refactoring too much of your code, we can just update the `updateInput()` function to this:

```
  updateInput = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    if (name === "email") {
      this.setState({
        inputs: {
          ...this.state.inputs,
          [name]: value
        },
        errors: {
          ...this.state.errors,
          email:
            value.includes("@") &&
            value.slice(-4).includes(".com")
              ? false
              : true
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        inputs: {
          ...this.state.inputs,
          [name]: value
        },
        errors: {
          ...this.state.errors,
          [name]: false
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

Also see sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/conditional-display-input-errors-vfmh5

Answer (score 0):

one possible way is to add a conditioning to your code like so

```
if((e.target.name === "email") && !this.validateEmail(inputs[e.target.name]) && (inputs[e.target.name].length !== 0 )   ){
     this.setState({
        errors: {
          ...this.state.errors,
          [e.target.name]: true,
        },
      }); 
    }        
 so after generally you will have something like this that add the validate function

validateEmail (email) {
    const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
    return re.test(email)
  } 

then your  unblur function will look like this

handleOnBlur = e => {
    const { inputs } = this.state;


     if (inputs[e.target.name].length === 0) {
       this.setState({
        errors: {
          ...this.state.errors,
          [e.target.name]: true,
        },
       });
      }
     if((e.target.name === "email") && !this.validateEmail(inputs[e.target.name]) && (inputs[e.target.name].length !== 0 )   ){
      this.setState({
        errors: {
          ...this.state.errors,
          [e.target.name]: true,
        },
      }); 
    }


  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the input Tag if you're using React and add `required` keyword at the end of the Tag.

```
<input
     className='p-3 flex w-full rounded-md text-black'
     type='email'
     name='Email'
     placeholder='Enter Email'
        required/>
```

It also should be inside a `form` Tag and a `button` of `type='submit'`
v