# Disable a button if empty input

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, dom-events

I would like the "Send" button to be disabled if the input is empty.
I want to manage this in the JavaScript file.
I know that it is possible in HTML to call a function on the input but I prefer to use an event in the js file.

https://codepen.io/leakcim-web/pen/gOYPpqo

```js
//javascript
let inputElt = document.getElementById('input');
let btn = document.getElementById('button');

if (inputElt.value !== '') {
  btn.disabled = false;
} else {
  btn.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter some text" name="name" id='input' />
<button id='button'>Réserver</button>
```

Comment: use `input` event

Comment: use addEventListener in your js to your inputElt, and update the btn disabled from the listener...

Comment: I had a similar problem and this question / answer helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: I posted my probelm and solution here if it helps anyone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65501771/changing-the-styling-of-the-form-submit-button-when-text-is-present-in-the-tex/65501815#65501815

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `addEventListener` to add an event to the textbox and enable/disable as appropriate

```js
let inputElt = document.getElementById('input');
let btn = document.getElementById('button');

inputElt.addEventListener("input", function(){
  btn.disabled = (this.value === '');
})
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter some text" name="name" id='input'/>
<button id='button' disabled>Réserver</button>
```

Comment: I would go with `btn.disabled = !this.value;` and by default set `disabled` property on the DOM instead of setting it in JS otherwise 

Comment: @AdrienMartinet I agree on setting disabled in the DOM. Updated. The logical check I chose to keep close to the OP, but your way would also work just fine.

Comment: It's worth including a call to [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), otherwise a string of white-space can be submitted (I realise that this isn't a stated requirement though).

Comment: Thank you for your help.

@Jamiec I do not understand this part: btn.disabled = (this.value === '');

Disabled is not boolean?

I do not understand why it is assigned the value this.value === ''

Comment: Yes Disable is a boolean attribute https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp :)

Comment: That's why you can shorten the assignment to `btn.disabled = !this.value;` or `btn.disabled = !this.value.trim();`

Answer (score 2):

Just as amusement, you can do this in just CSS and html, reference [Matching an empty input box using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617020/matching-an-empty-input-box-using-css)

```css
#input:invalid + button {
    opacity: 0.5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter some text" name="name" id='input' required="required"/>
<button id='button'>Réserver</button>
```

And if you have something in between the button and input you can use `#input ~ #button.` also you don't need the id attributes you can use `type="submit"` on button then use `input ~ [type="submit"]` then it will work with any input at the same nesting.

Comment: Interesting alternative :) Thank you

Comment: Amazing solution! I love it, thanks a lot!