# How can I highlight optional input:text if it isn't empty?

Tags: javascript, css, forms

I found solution for `:required` inputs but nothing for `:optional`.

Thank you for help and sorry for my English, this isn't my native language.

Comment: When do you want to highlight the input? Perhaps when the user hovers above it or have a focus on that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** If you're targeting modern browsers and using a placeholder (or you *can* use a placeholder), you can use [Irina's `:placeholder-shown`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62039723/157247) pseudo-class below rather than `.empty)` and do away with the JavaScript. It doesn't work in IE or Edge v44 or earlier, but works in all up-to-date modern browsers. But: You can use `-ms-input-placeholder` for IE and Edge v44 and earlier, making the JavaScript part of the below defunct. But I don't want to edit it to use `:placeholder-shown` and `:-ms-input-placeholder` because that duplicates Irina's answer (somewhat), and I can't remove this answer because it's accepted. See the end of the answer for an example, though.

---

> I found solution for :required inputs but nothing for :optional.

Two ways you can do that:

1. You can use `:not(:required)`. `:not` is the [negation pseudoclass](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#negation). It accepts a [simple selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#simple-selectors-dfn) and inverts its meaning. "Not required" is "optional."
2. You can style all of the inputs in the "optional" way, then override that styling for `:required` elements.

Unfortunately, though, the "empty" part of your question can't be answered with CSS alone for `input` elements that are optional ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3617050/157247)).

Here's an example of #1, using JavaScript to add/remove a class when the input is/isn't empty:

```js
"use strict";
function toggleEmptyClass(el) {
    if (el.tagName === "INPUT") {
        // If you need IE compatibility, you'll need an `if`/`else`;
        // IE doesn't support the second argument for `toggle`
        el.classList.toggle("empty", !el.value);
    }
}
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(toggleEmptyClass);
document.addEventListener("input", function() {
    toggleEmptyClass(event.target);
});
```

```css
input:not(.empty):required {
    background-color: #FF8000;
}
input:not(.empty):not(:required) {
    background-color: #0080FF;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label>
        Required:
        <input type="text" required value="required">
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Required and (initially) empty:
        <input type="text" required>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Optional:
        <input type="text" value="optional">
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Optional and (initially) empty:
        <input type="text">
    </label>
</div>
```

---

Or you can just style all `input` elements with the "optional" style, and then override it for `:required` elements:

Example:

```js
"use strict";
function toggleEmptyClass(el) {
    if (el.tagName === "INPUT") {
        // If you need IE compatibility, you'll need an `if`/`else`;
        // IE doesn't support the second argument for `toggle`
        el.classList.toggle("empty", !el.value);
    }
}
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(toggleEmptyClass);
document.addEventListener("input", function() {
    toggleEmptyClass(event.target);
});
```

```css
input:not(.empty) {
    background-color: #0080FF;
}
input:not(.empty):required {
    background-color: #FF8000;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label>
        Required:
        <input type="text" required value="required">
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Required and (initially) empty:
        <input type="text" required>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Optional:
        <input type="text" value="optional">
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Optional and (initially) empty:
        <input type="text">
    </label>
</div>
```

---

Here's a full example showing doing the above with `:placeholder-shown` and the older Microsoft-specific `-ms-input-placeholder`:

```css
input:not(:placeholder-shown):required {
    background-color: #FF8000;
}
input:not(:placeholder-shown):not(:required) {
    background-color: #0080FF;
}
/* IE and Edge <= v44 support: */
input:not(:-ms-input-placeholder):required {
    background-color: #FF8000;
}
input:not(:-ms-input-placeholder):not(:required) {
    background-color: #0080FF;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label>
        Required:
        <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder" required value="required">
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Required and (initially) empty:
        <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder" required>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Optional:
        <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder" value="optional">
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Optional and (initially) empty:
        <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder">
    </label>
</div>
```

Or, again, styling all of them and then overriding just the `:required` to be different:

```css
input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
    background-color: #0080FF;
}
input:not(:placeholder-shown):required {
    background-color: #FF8000;
}
/* IE and Edge <= v44 support: */
input:not(:-ms-input-placeholder) {
    background-color: #0080FF;
}
input:not(:-ms-input-placeholder):required {
    background-color: #FF8000;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label>
        Required:
        <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder" required value="required">
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Required and (initially) empty:
        <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder" required>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Optional:
        <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder" value="optional">
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Optional and (initially) empty:
        <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder">
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't use this method. In this case the styles will be shown always, but I need them only in case when input is not empty.

Comment: @IrinaZorg - Unfortunately, there is no CSS selector for an empty/non-empty `input` element, only valid/invalid, which (I think you already know) doesn't help with optional inputs. You need to use JavaScript for that. :-(

Comment: @IrinaZorg are you looking for this: https://jsfiddle.net/ogzw0a64/1/ ?

Comment: @IrinaZorg - I've updated the answer to show using JavaScript to toggle a class for use in the CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Found this solution, using [`:placeholder-shown`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#placeholder):

```css
input:placeholder-shown {
  border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
}

input {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(
    171.2deg,
    #ffc1d4 15.78%,
    #ff866c 76.58%
  );
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name1" id="" placeholder="placeholder1" optional>
  <input type="text" name="name2" id="" placeholder="placeholder2" optional>
</form>
```

Comment: Very cool!! Beware that `:placeholder-shown` doesn't work in any version of IE, and doesn't work in Edge v44 or earlier (which are still current on most Windows installations -- though not for much longer, since Chromium-based Edge v79 came out in January and is incrementally being added to auto-update).

Comment: Note that you'll still want `:not(:required)` or similar to avoid styling required elements.

Comment: Ah! But see the comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35593489/157247): There's a Microsoft-specific version that works on IE: `:-ms-input-placeholder`. So if you use both (in separate but equivalent rules), you're covered for IE and Edge v44 and before.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution using javascript and css

CSS:

```
.highlighted
      {
        border: hsl(180, 60%, 60%) 2px solid;
      }
```

JS:

```
        let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:optional');
        for (let input of inputs)
        {
            input.addEventListener('change',function(e)
            {
              if (this.value != '')
              {
                this.classList.add('highlighted');
              }
              else
              {
                this.classList.remove('highlighted');
              }
            });
        }
```